# Passing in all arguments

Tags: r

Consider the following:

```
foo <- function(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 1, e = 2, f = 3, g = 4, h = 1) {
    print(h)
    bar(a = a, b = b, c = c, d = d, e = e, f = f, g = g)
    foobar(c = c, e = e, g = g)
}

bar <- function(a, b, c, d, e, f, g) {
    a + b + c + d + e + f * g
}

foobar <- function(c, e, g) {
    if (c) {
         print(g +  e)
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3, 4,5, 6, 7, 8)
```

I have something similar to the above where I have subfunction calls that require a lot of the variables passed down from the level above it. Is there an easier way of doing lines 3 and 4 of this code, rather than manually listing out each variable each time it calls it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we can create a helper function to make this easier

```
call_match_args <- function(fun, data) {
  fun <- match.fun(fun)
  seeking <- names(formals(fun))
  stopifnot(all(seeking %in% names(data)))
  do.call(fun, data[seeking], envir=parent.frame())
}
```

this will take a function and a list and will pass all the values of the list that match the function parameters names as arguments. The `do.call` function takes care of turning the list into parameters.

Then we can change your `foo` function to look something like this

```
foo <- function(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 1, e = 2, f = 3, g = 4, h = 1) {
  vars <- mget(ls())
  print(vars$h)
  call_match_args(bar, vars)
  call_match_args(foobar, vars)
}

foo(1, 2, 3, 4,5, 6, 7, 8)
# [1] 8
# [1] 12
```

while `bar` and `foobar` can stay the same. The first step in the function it to take all the parameter values and put them in a list. Then you access them from that list and can pass that list to the `call_match_args` helper function.